Is Lutheran communion theology consistent?
I am trying to understand the Lutheran doctrine of Communion. Lutherans believe that Christ "gives us his true body and blood in, with, and under the consecrated bread and wine" (Small Catechism with explanation Concordia Publishing House, 352). They believe that Christ's real presence is there whether the communicant believes it or not (353), because the presence of Christ is established by the words of Jesus that are read during the ceremony. While my  Small Catechism doesn't say this, I am also of the understanding that the real presence is also not dependent on the faith of the pastor leading the ceremony. In this way, a communicant does not need to worry about whether the pastor or the congregation is faithful; Christ's word is sufficient for him to be sure that he is in fact receiving Christ's body and blood for his forgiveness.
However, Lutherans apparently believe that, at churches (such as Baptists) who do not affirm the real presence, Christ is not present in the communion elements, even if the words of institution are read. This appears to also be the case even if the communicant believes that Christ is present in the elements at such a church.
I don't understand how those ideas can be reconciled. If it is Christ's words, not the faith of the recipient nor the faith of the minister, that effectuates the real presence of Christ in Communion, how is it that that word is ineffective if the sacrament is administered in a church of the wrong denomination?
Perhaps one might say that if most or almost all of the congregation doesn't believe in real presence, then Christ's body will not be really present. But then we lose that assurance solely in Christ's Word that he is really present and we must also trust the congregation that we are with.
Is there something that I am missing here? How do Lutherans reconcile these beliefs?
Note: I am not asking whether or not Lutherans are correct on this issue. I am asking asking whether the Lutheran beliefs about Communion are internally consistent. If I have misunderstood any part of the Lutheran doctrines here, please let me know what I got wrong.

Good question! +1. As an aside, w.r.t. "Christ's real presence is there whether the communicant believes it or not", consider also 1 Corinthians 11:29, "anyone who eats and drinks without discerning the body eats and drinks judgment on himself". This not only seems to support that the Presence is not contingent on the belief of the receiver, but also seems to affirm the Presence more generally.

I think there may be a misunderstanding? Since u bring up the small catechism of Luther I will use that. He answers this question*

Who, then, receives such Sacrament worthily?
Answer: Fasting and bodily preparation is, indeed, a fine outward training; but he is truly worthy and well prepared who has faith in these words: Given, and shed for you, for the remission of sins.
But he that does not believe these words, or doubts, is unworthy and unfit; for the words For you require altogether believing hearts.

So since Baptist and many other Prots do not believe in the real presence of Christ in communion and the remission of sins then it is just ineffective because one does not have faith in the words being spoken to them and their remission of sins.

There is a different between the sacrament being effective and Christ's actual presence in the elements. Article 353 says that everyone who receives the sacrament receives Christ's body, but "only those who believe receive it to their blessing". I am asking about the "receiving" and not the "receiving to their blessing"

@DarkMalthorp I am a bit confused by the question, as I  have never heard a Lutheran state that at Baptist communion Christ is not present, the doctrine of real presence is that Christ is present whether or not the person believes so or not, it is the blessing that is ineffective if the person does not believe Christ presence and words in communion, I'm sorry if I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

so is it correct Lutheran theology that Christ's real presence is also present in Baptist communions? Can you give a citation on that? I actually have heard a Lutheran pastor make the claim that Christ isn't present in churches who don't believe that, and it would also explain why Lutherans discourage congregants from taking communion at churches of other denominations

E.g. I heard a Lutheran pastor say that if he had to choose between taking communion at a Catholic Church or a Baptist Church, he would take it at the Catholic Church because "at least I'll be getting something". This even though in general he would acknowledge greater agreement with Baptist theology than Catholic

It would be correct that Christ is present in Communion no matter where you take it, as long as the words of Christ are said, If the words of Christ are not said, then it is not Communion.  I think you are taking the words of one pastor and attributing it to Lutheran doctrine. Maybe certain Baptist do not say the words? ik they attribute it as a purely symbolic thing. In certainty you can say that because of that they are committing sin as stated in 1 Corinthians 11:27 Because they do not believe in the words or the real presence of Christ, that may also attribute to what the pastor said.

@DarkMalthorp, FYI in reply to Lutherans not communing with non-Lutherans, see this other Answer. The focus of the Question is more on non-Lutherans in a Lutheran church, but I point out why, by the same principles, a Lutheran ought not commune outside of the Lutheran church. I think whether the premise of this Question is faulty is a good question. I also wouldn't exclude the possibility that a pastor contemplating communing with RCCs is already outside Lutheran orthodoxy.

@Matthew Fair, but in context it was "if I was forced to choose", not like something he would actually do.
